# How to remove custom logging using proguard?

Tags: proguard

I want to remove some custom logging from my app using proguard. My code looks like this:

```
public void foo() {

    MyLogItem item = new MyLogItem();

    // I want to remove all of these item.addText() calls:
    item.addText("apple");
    item.addText("pizza");
    item.addText("noodles and "
        + " more noodles");
}
```

How could I specify that in my proguard file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the precise signatures of MyLogItem, it would look something like this:

```
-assumenosideeffects public class mylogging.MyLogItem {
    public MyLogItem();
    public void addTest(java.lang.String);
}
```

This option is only applied if optimization is not disabled.

You should check the results by looking at the processed code with a tool like javap (or with ProGuard's -dump option).

Comment: Thanks, my MyLogItem class has other methods in it. Do I need to add all of them to the definition you provided to get it to work?

Comment: Only the main logging methods.

Comment: Ah ok, so I have -dontoptimize in my proguard file. I'll have to turn that on to get it to work and will have to test all again, also will look to see if this is something we should be doing for android apps. I'll report back after that, thanks again.